# How to resolve deprecation calls

Tags: deprecation-warning, symfony-3.1

My project is developed with Symfony 3.1.0 with PHP 7.0 and I use many bundles

Since few days I have many deprecations and sometimes the toolbar return JS error `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Can you help me on the methodology to resolve deprecations ?

How to understand logs ? Should I correct my code ? Update some bundles ? Witch ones ?

Thanks !

My composer file :

```
{
    "name": "xxx",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "description": "xxx",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.1.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "~2.3",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "2.0.0-alpha1",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "1.1.0",
        "symfony/form": "3.1.0",
        "javiereguiluz/easyadmin-bundle": "~1.14",
        "cmen/google-charts-bundle": "1.*",
        "blackknight467/star-rating-bundle": "^2.0",
        "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.5.x-dev",
        "suncat/mobile-detect-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "cspoo/swiftmailer-mailgun-bundle": "^0.3.1",
        "php-http/guzzle5-adapter": "^1.0",
        "symfony/finder": "^3.2",
        "nategood/httpful": "^0.2.20",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.22",
        "algolia/algolia-search-bundle": "^2.1",
        "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.0",
        "coresphere/console-bundle": "^0.5.0",
        "robertotru/to-inline-style-email-bundle": "^1.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "5.4.4",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "3.1.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

My deprecations :

```
Referencing the "core" extension by its name (defined by getName()) is deprecated since 1.26 and will be removed in Twig 2.0. Use the Fully Qualified Extension Class Name instead. (2 times)

Referencing the "form" extension by its name (defined by getName()) is deprecated since 1.26 and will be removed in Twig 2.0. Use the Fully Qualified Extension Class Name instead. (70 times)

Calling "renderblock" on template "@WebProfiler/Collector/request.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "@WebProfiler/Collector/time.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead).

Calling "renderblock" on template "@WebProfiler/Collector/memory.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "@WebProfiler/Collector/ajax.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "@WebProfiler/Collector/form.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Silent display of undefined block "toolbar" in template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/base.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.29 and will throw an exception in 2.0. Use the "block('toolbar') is defined" expression to test for block existence

Calling "renderblock" on template "@WebProfiler/Collector/exception.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "@WebProfiler/Collector/logger.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Silent display of undefined block "toolbar" in template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/base.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.29 and will throw an exception in 2.0. Use the "block('toolbar') is defined" expression to test for block existence.

Calling "renderblock" on template "@WebProfiler/Collector/events.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "@WebProfiler/Collector/router.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

 Calling "renderblock" on template "@WebProfiler/Collector/translation.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "@Security/Collector/security.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "@WebProfiler/Collector/twig.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "@Doctrine/Collector/db.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "@Swiftmailer/Collector/swiftmailer.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "@Debug/Profiler/dump.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "@EasyAdmin/data_collector/easyadmin.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "MobileDetectBundle:Collector:device.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "CoreSphereConsoleBundle:Toolbar:toolbar.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

Calling "renderblock" on template "@WebProfiler/Collector/config.html.twig" from template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0. Use block("toolbar", template) instead)

... etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

For these notices :

> Silent display of undefined block "toolbar" in template "@WebProfiler/Profiler/base.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.29 and will throw an exception in 2.0. Use the "block('toolbar') is defined" expression to test for block existence

You must correct your *base.html.twig* file :

```
{% include('Bundle::file.html.twig') with {stylesheets: block('stylesheets')} %}
```

Like :

```
{% set sheets = null %}
{% if block('stylesheets') is defined %}
   {% set sheets = block('stylesheets') %}
{% endif %}

{% include('Bundle::file.html.twig') with {stylesheets: sheets} %}
```